# How to clear or delete or invisible the border line of Framelayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

Here there is a square border around framelayout which i want to delete on click listener
Kindly request any suitable solution for that.

```
        ivFetchimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        StickerImageView iv_sticker = new StickerImageView(getApplicationContext());
        iv_sticker.setImageDrawable(ivFetchimage.getDrawable());
        int getScreenWidth = Other.getScreenWidth(getApplicationContext()) / 2;
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(getScreenWidth, getScreenWidth);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        iv_sticker.setLayoutParams(params);

        frameLayoutcanvas.removeAllViews();
        frameLayoutcanvas.addView(iv_sticker);

        frameLayoutcanvas.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        frameLayoutcanvas.bringToFront();
```

Here there is my xml code

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/vg_canvas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fetchimage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please help me to clear the border on touch listener.

Comment: I guess you want to border this ImageView. Instead of set border for FrameLayout, you can RelativeLayout and add 1 more view overlap ImageView, then set border for this view. Now you can set visible or invisible for this border view.

Comment: i cant set border to imageview i'll have to use framelayout as i did but now i want to invisible the border.

Comment: Set FramLayout Background as Transparent Color.

Comment: it didn't work @Chetan

Answer (score 0):

@chiragdulera this is my mean:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <yourFrameLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   </yourFrameLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/borderView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_background_outlet" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And drawable transparent_background_outlet look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
         <solid android:color="#00000000" />
         <stroke android:color="#000000" android:width="2dp"/>
    </shape>
```

Now setting visible or invisible borderView, it's up to you.

Comment: yeah! thats the user defined borderview but i dont want to add border i want to remove the borderline which i have with framelayout.